# telephone sockets connecting them to an ATA

Tags: voip

We have many extension sockets in the house therefore be fairly expensive to buy an ata for each phone. Since extension sockets are daisy chained together, could I just plug it into the FXS socket instead of the BT master socket? Or is the FXS port strictly for one phone  only?

Answer (score 1):

Most ATA FXS port can support multiple phones... they're typically spec for 3 to 5 REN.  So should be ok.